# PHP Foreach Loop Array Access

Tags: php, loops, foreach

In this foreach loop:

```
<?php
$x=array("one","two","three");
foreach ($x as $value)
{
   echo $value . "<br>";
}
?>
```

How will you be able to access the string "two" individually outside the foreach loop? I don't need to print it, I just need to know how to access it.

Comment: try to use `$x[1]` and try to read [***manual***](http://php.net/array).

Comment: Do you want to detect if "two" is in the array? Find its index? What?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what I am trying to find out is how to access the values inside $value. Is that possible?

Comment: Jon, I want to know how to access "two". What I did was to push the values from the foreach loop to an array inside a javascript code. My javascript, indeed, stored the values inside the array. However, it just got the first element. So, in effect, what I got inside my array is "one","one","one".

Answer (score 6):

Access it by index. The loop is not necessary for that:

```
echo $x[0]; // one
echo $x[1]; // two
echo $x[2]; // three
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just like this.

```
$x[1] // two
```

For further information , Read this under [Example #1 A simple array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the array direct without the effect of the foreach loop.

```
$x[1]
```